# show only 2 panels in JColorChooser

Tags: java, swing, jcolorchooser

I want to display only "Swartches" and "RGB" panel.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.colorchooser.AbstractColorChooserPanel;

public class ColorPickerSample {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String hex = "#ff0033";

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        // Create and set up the window.
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Centered");

        // Display the window.
        frame.setSize(50, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // set flow layout for the frame
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("");
        System.out.println(Color.decode(hex));
        button.setBackground(Color.decode(hex));
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JColorChooser cc = new JColorChooser();
                AbstractColorChooserPanel defaultPanels[] = cc.getChooserPanels();
                cc.removeChooserPanel(defaultPanels[1]);
                cc.removeChooserPanel(defaultPanels[2]);
                cc.removeChooserPanel(defaultPanels[4]);
            //  frame.getContentPane().add(cc);
                //Color color = cc.showDialog(frame, "Choose a color", Color.blue);
                }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:

        //creating and showing this application's GUI.

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                createAndShowGUI(); 

            }

        });
    }

}
```

How can I show 2 panels only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API also has a `removeChooserPanel(...)` method.

So I guess you could do something like:

```
AbstractColorChooserPanel defaultPanels[] = cc.getChooserPanels();
cc.removeChooserPanel( defaultPanels[4] ); // CMYK
cc.removeChooserPanel( defaultPanels[2] );  // HSL
...
```

Edit:

> I am not sure how would I display this modified chooser in panel

You will need to use the `createDialog(...)` method of the JColorChooser:

```
JDialog dialog = JColorChooser.createDialog(
    frame.getContentPane(),
    "Choose a Color",
    true,
    cc,
    null,
    null);
dialog.setVisible(true);
System.out.println( cc.getColor() );
```

Comment: I tired that but I couldn't make it work. I have edited the code in main question

Comment: @user1631306, Your posted code works fine for me (in the future post the code WITH the question so we don't have to guess what you may have tried). Of course you actually need to display the chooser in the frame, but once I did that I only see "Swatches" and "RGB". I'm using JDK 8 on Windows 7.

Comment: Sure, I will keep that in mind. I am not sure how would I display this modified chooser in panel. Can I do it like "Color color = cc.showDialog(frame, "Choose a color", Color.blue);"

Comment: it works. one last thing. How would I use this modified JcolorChooser "cc" to show a dialogue box. Using "Color color = cc.showDialog(frame, "Choose a color", Color.blue);", brings the original color panels.

Comment: But this wont return me the chosen color, like I was getting earlier when I used " showDialog"

Comment: @user1631306, `I am not sure how would I display this modified chooser in panel.` - I see what you mean. See edit.